# Expression type is ambiguous without more context for Array of arrays of typealias

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to create an array of arrays of a typealias object - but I'm getting a "Expression type is ambiguous without more context" compilation error.
Here's my code:

```
typealias TestClosure = ((message: String)->())
var testArray = [[TestClosure]](count: 4, repeatedValue: nil)
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Turns out that when the array of arrays is an array of optionals it does compile:

```
var testArray = [[TestClosure]?](count: 4, repeatedValue: nil)
```

But - I want to make sure the initial array will hold actual empty arrays.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 2**

Use `repeatedValue` to create the empty arrays:

```
var testArray = Array(count: 4, repeatedValue: [TestClosure]())
```

**Swift 3**

The syntax has changed but it's the same idea:

```
var testArray = Array(repeating: [TestClosure](), count: 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` to create the empty arrays instead of `nil`:

**Swift 3:**

```
typealias TestClosure = (String) -> ()
var testArray = [[TestClosure]](repeating: [], count: 4)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
typealias TestClosure = ((message: String) -> ())
var testArray = [[TestClosure]](count: 4, repeatedValue: [])
```